# Save a model with keras

Tags: python, keras

I use the method save_model and load_mode but it don't work.

I have an error : AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'get_config'
I don't know if I use correctly this method. I show my code for take an example:

```
gridSearch = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier,
                          param_grid = parameters,
                          scoring = "accuracy",
                          cv = 10)
gridSearch.fit(X_train, y_train)
save_model(gridSearch, filepath = 'monModele.h5')
```

The result is the error attribute Error. Can you help me to find a solution for this problem or to find an other method to save and load a keras model.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `GridSearchCV` is not a Keras model, but a module from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) that also has a `fit` function with a similar API.

In order to use `save_model` and `load_model` you need the actual Keras model, my guess is it is your `classifier`. Specifically, an instance of the [Model](https://keras.io/models/model/) class from Keras.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. I have a question so How u do to save a model you ?